# Unable to get instance of seleniumLibrary in robotframework

Tags: python-3.x, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I am using robot framework with python. I am trying to get seleniumLibrary instance in python file using following code

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class PythonDemo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myInstance = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
```

When i try use self.myInstance to populate keywords, its not showing in .py file.

In .robot file, i can easily access robot and seleniumLibrary keywords. But unable to use seleniumLibrary instance in .python file

**Below are configuration details-**

```
Pycharm community edition 2020.3
robotframework                 3.2.2,
robotframework-pythonlibcore   2.1.0,
robotframework-ride            1.7.4.2,
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 3.3.1,
selenium                       4.1.0,
python 3.8.0,
plugin - intellibot@seleniumLibrary Patched.
```

is there any setting in Pycharm? or am i missing anything?

Could anybody please help me with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _"its not showing in .py file"_? What does "showing" mean here? What happens when you run the test and try to execute your keyword?

Comment: Hi Bryan, my apologies, what i meant is, when i try to use
self.myInstance = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary'). I want to use self.myInstance to get keywords from seleniumlibrary in my python file. Its not auto suggesting in pycharm

Comment: So your issue is with autocomplete?

Comment: Yes FLAK-ZOSO. My issue is regarding autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

**Not Possible** - you will get `RobotNotRunning` exception if you just try to acquire "instance" of a library via `BuiltIn()` if the python code you have is executed directly and not by adding `Library   YourPythonCodeLib` to settings section of the "your_test_or_task.robot".

Comment: Hi rasjani, i am not executing python code directly. I want to use seleniumlibrary keywords in python file by using self.myInstance = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary').  When i try use self.myInstance to access keywords..its not auto suggesting or auto complete in pycharm editor

Comment: Not possible. Just learn the api ;)